# Database design for frequent select and insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I'd like to know the best database design for the following case.

I use `Spring` and `Sql Server` and my case could be simplified as follow:

Let say there're three tables here:

**Item:**

- id(unique,primary-key,auto-increase)
- name
- category

**Address:**

- id(unique,primary-key,auto-increase)
- address
- postcode

**Order:**

- id(unique,primary-key,auto-increase)
- price
- date
- itemId(foreign-key)
- addressId(foreign-key)

The business logic is `Spring` handling the incoming message including the information of Item, Address and Order.

If the incoming item data exists in database(exist means the name and category are identical), return the id of that record. It it doesn't exist, insert a new record and return the new id.

Address is pretty much the same. If the incoming address data exists in database(exist means the address and postcode are identical), return the id of that record. It it doesn't exist, insert a new record and return the new id.

And then insert into the order table with previous item id and address id as foreign key.

What I did right now is put all this select and insert logic into one stored procedure to reduce the latency between communication of server and database.

I'm wondering if there's better solution for this case.

---

Updates:

Here's the `Proc` I use:

```
CREATE procedere spInsert

--list of parameters

set @tmpItemId = (select id from item where name=@name and category=@category)

if @tmpItemId is NULL

   begin 
       insert to item values(@name,@category)
       set @tmpItemId=@@IDENTITY
   end

--the same logic applied to Address

insert into order values(@price,@date,@tmpItemId,@tmpAddressId)
```

After testing for a while, the speed is not satisfied and it takes around 10-20 seconds to insert 100 records.

May I ask any methods to improve?

BTW, I think the bottleneck of the store procedure is about select the id every time and insert frequently. What about using `uuid` for the index of the table rather than auto-increase index in database? In that way, Java side could handle the select part because Java side provides `uuid` and the sql server only cares about the `insert`

Is it a good choice?

Answer (score 0):

What you have planned to handle all these 3 database transactions in one stored procedure is the best solution unless you forsee a deadlock situation, that is multiple users trying to add the same Order (same address and item) at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Using a stored procedure is a great way to reduce time in network traffic. You're on track there.

Here are two possible data modeling tweaks:

1. If you know all of your items/categories ahead of time, you could **pre-populate the data**. That way its just a select to get the ID.  Then you're doing all the insert work ahead of time.
2. You could take it a step further by changing the item table to **use a natural key** (name and category). *Then you don't even have to touch the item table* in this scenario. The downside is that you would have to store the whole item name, and category on the order table.  So you would be sacrificing some storage space for speeding up the process. A side benefit is that reading the order table would use one less join to get the item name and category.

Comment: 1.Unfortunately, I'm not aware of all data of `item`/`address`(you mean `address` not category, right?). So it seems **pre-population** is not feasible. But `item`/`address` are not changing very frequently I believe because items are not infinite. The problem is only when the message comes in do I know what the item is.

Comment: 2. I'm afraid it's not gonna to work either because I simplify the column to just two columns. In fact, the number of columns in `item`/`address` are far more than that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Like you said,you are not showing the complete table design.So whatever is visible appear good .
2. So now everything depend upon proc content and at a time how much and what content you are passing to this proc .
3. Hopefully itemid and addressid is not null in order table.Say for example itemid is new but addressid already exists,so how you are inserting/handling this situation in order table or your proc.
4. Like you can use TVP,merge,similar topic is discuss here in this link, http://forums.asp.net/p/1956468/5582681.aspx?Re+Insert+Millions+of+records

Comment: Please see the updated store procedures. Everyday I need to read around 500MB raw text message into database as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are several factors to consider when selecting a design. Here are a couple to start with:

1. How big is the data set?
   If the data set is small then your solution will work.  As number of rows increases, the text searches may slow down. An awesomely large database may not be able to use auto-increase values for the id.
2. Are there more business rules that have to be handled? For example, if an exact match isn't found, will the program return close matches? How logic and error handling for business rules is implemented can make a difference. If there are a lot of rules around validating a good row of items, addresses or orders, it may be better to separate the code into different stored procedures to make it easier to debug and to isolate the ripple effect of changes to code. The future always seems to bring changing business environments.
3. To make the tables more readable, in Item name the key itemId and in the Address table name the key addressId. Try to eliminate assumptions because no two people have exactly the same experience and may draw different initial conclusions from names.
4. The actual business rules and insert code could go into triggers on the tables. Then the stored procedure would insert into item and on success insert into address and on success insert into order. That would make the individual execution plans simpler which should make optimization easier to figure out. Again, having the business rules split up cuts down on the scope maintenance and testing.

Comment: 1. The data set isn't so small I think because everyday I need to read around 500M raw text message into database as soon as possible. 2.please refer to the update stored procedures, that's all the logic. Record found, get id; not found, insert and return new id. 3.4. not so understandable. Please help to specify

Comment: How are the name and category fields defined? Are they indexed? Is category a look up item set up so you search on an INT? When you check for existing, are you sending a lot of data across the network? IE, it could be faster to just send the filter fields across to check for initial existence instead of the whole record if the row has a lot of fields or a lot of data in the fields.

Comment: What version of SQL Server is being used? There are a variety of DMOs that can help identify query stats like Disk I/O or missing indexes, etc.

Comment: column `name` and `category` aren't index, with the type of `varchar`. When checking existence, only the parameters are sent to db in a `Map`  format. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Have you tried adding an index on name and category followed by recompiling the stored procedure yet? Here is an article on finding missing indexes for SQL Server 2008. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/01/03/sql-server-2008-missing-index-script-download/

Comment: I have read that explicitly listing the fields to insert into is another way to speed up inserts. The line above would become:   insert into item (name, category) values(@name,@category)

Comment: Any material proving that `insert into item (name, category) values(@name,@category)` is faster then `insert into item values(@name,@category)`

Comment: Here is a list of best practices for SQL Server queries: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jamesw/archive/2011/10/03/a-list-of-sql-best-practices.aspx   One of the training kit books explained that explicit references mean the SQL Server engine does not have to take time to match columns up. Admittedly, this is a small change, but it may make some difference with large imports.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is good enough for frequent select and insert. you don't need change other solution.